# Auto documentation in android studio no longer goes away automatically, and have to manually close. How do I re-enable the default behavior?

Tags: android-studio

I somehow turned the documentation popup to be manually closed. It's incredibly annoying and I can't find the setting to undo it. Whatever I did adds maximize, minimize buttons and these windows have to be manually closed now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out. It's called pinned mode. I got into it by clicking the pin icon on the window at the top right. Of course once you're in pinned mode, and you try to deselect it from the gear, nothing happens.

#### How to fix

1. enable toolbars
2. hit the red X to restore popup

[image]